# Return array from function in c++ lib into c# programm

Tags: c#, c++, dll, function-pointers

I need return integer values in c++ lib into c#.
In c++ lib it return pointer, because I know, that in c++ we cannot return an array. I need that integer values to operate in c#

```
__declspec(dllexport) int* FindShortestPath(int from, int to)
        {
            //some algorithm...

            return showShortestPathTo(used, p, to); 
}

static int* showShortestPathTo(vector<bool> used, vector<int> p, int vertex)
{
   vector<int> path;

  //push to vector values

  int* return_array = new int[path.size()];

  //initialize array dynamically.....

  return return_array;
}
```

The question is : what is the best way return values from c++ library into c#?
What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal way is to let the caller pass an array that you fill in with your C function.  Like this:

```
int FindShortestPath(int from, int to, int[] buffer, int bufsize)
```

Now the C# code can simply pass an int[] as the *buffer* argument.  Copy the vector content into it.  Be sure to observe *bufsize*, you are copying directly into the GC heap so if you copy beyond the end of the array then you'll destroy that heap.

If *bufsize* is too small then return an error code, negative numbers are good.  Otherwise return the actual number of copied elements.  If the C# code cannot guess at the required buffer size then a convention is to first call the function with a *null* buffer.  Return the required array size, the C# code can now allocate the array and call the function again.